# How to react on (+,-,*/) in my calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In c# I am using this code to imediately react on press keys.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{


            if (keyData == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                button_1.PerformClick();
                return true;
            }
}
```

I defined this for all numpad numbers and it WORKS great. But I am not able to define this function for (/,*,-,+) on NumPad. I have read some topics with solution throw keyCode...it was like if(e.keykode==46) than something. But it worked after i pressed enter. I need imediatly reaction no keys +,-,*,/. Can somebody help me pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Keys.Add`, `Keys.Divide`, `Keys.Multiply`, and `Keys.Subtract`, I believe.

To use them, that would be exactly the same as you have already done:

```
if(keyData == Keys.Multiply) { // or Add, Divide, or Subtract
     btnMultiply.PerformClick(); // Or whatever else you want to do here.
}
```

Comment: I am begginer with C Sharp....can you write me a code how exactly to do that pls?

Comment: I am sorry that I dont understand but Keys.Multiply doesnt define that i want reaction on key "/". How to define that it should be "/"?

Comment: See where my comment "or Add, Divide, or Subtract" is? You can replace `Multiply` with `Divide` for `/`, or `Add` for `+`, or `Subtract` for `-`.

Comment: Can u also tell me how it should look for "." on numeric keyboard? Its the last key i need.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this to occur in an event like so:

```
    private void txtText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
          {
             //do something
          }
    }
```

Something like this should work for you.

Comment: This is the same.....in this function is no define that i want a reaction od key "/". :(